# Semi-automated music video editing - cut on beat or MIDI note

Tags: linux, open-source, music, video-editing, midi

I'm looking for a way to automate my video editing because I keep doing the same thing that could for the most part be done by a program, at least in theory.

I usually have a song (in .wav file format) and a bunch of video clips and I want to generate one video that has the length of that song.

- I take all my clips and mark all sections that are usable and all sections that are unusable.
- Then I put marks in the usable sections, wherever the scenery changes significantly.
- Then I make one large video file concatenating all the usable footage (keeping the markings in mind)
- Then I put marks in the audio file everywhere I want it to cut (usually on certain beats or notes of specific instruments).
- Then I put marks in the audio file everywhere I want it to start and end an effect.
- Then I put the audio file along with the concatenated video into my editing software (Kdenlive).
- Then I insert the concatenated video at the beginning of the song and at the first mark in the song, I cut the video to skip to the next video mark.
- At the second mark in the audio, I again cut the video to skip to the next video mark.
- In case of a cross-fade-effect-start mark in the audio, I align the video in a way that it starts cross-fading to the next video mark making the cross-fade finish, once the next audio mark is reached.
- In case a video section is not long enough to go from one audio mark to the next, it skips to the next section that is long enough.
- This process is repeated until the video has the length of the song.

When I say marks, I mean that I write down the time stamps.

It needs to work on Linux and it must be achieved using open source software.

Any suggestions on how to make this process more efficient? Is there maybe a piece of software that would fit my needs better?